# Filtering SaltStack output

Tags: command-line-interface, provisioning, salt-stack, orchestration

When running commands on lots of salt minions, it can be difficult to properly make sense of the output. What we usually do was

`salt '*somefilter*' state.apply some.thing`

Now, if there are 50 guests and a few have a problem, this can get lost in the commandline output.

Is there a way to filter the output to only get feedback about failed states? Or in general a better way to 'parse' the output (as a human) than scrollback a huge buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the following alias for salt to get less output: `alias salt='salt --state-output=mixed --state-verbose=False'` - on 50 minions it is still not a breeze to read the output - but it is a bit better than the full response.

Read more about the options in [the cli docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/cli/salt.html#output-options) and the [highstate docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/output/all/salt.output.highstate.html).